# Combining 2 mysql queries using subqueries

Tags: mysql, subquery

I was wondering if anybody here could help with a problem I am having. I am trying to combine 2 mysql queries into one query using sub queries. I currently have the 2 queries separatly which produce the results i want:

Here are the 2 queries:

```
SELECT contact_id FROM contacts 
WHERE acc_id = 1 AND email LIKE "paul%"

SELECT c0.contact_id 
FROM contact_tags c0 INNER JOIN contact_tags c1 
on c0.contact_id = c1.contact_id INNER JOIN contact_tags c2 
on c1.contact_id = c2.contact_id where c0.tag_id = 1 
AND c1.tag_id = 2 AND c2.tag_id = 3
```

Here is some example data from the tables:

```
Contacts:

contact_id    acc_id     email
    54          1        paul@test.com

Tags:

id     contact_id     tag_id 
1         54            1
2         54            2
3         54            3
4         50            1
5         50            2
```

Both queries when run independently produce this result which is correct:

```
contact_id
    54
```

However I am trying to nest one query inside the other to produce the same result from a single query:

Here is what I have tried:

```
SELECT c0.contact_id 
FROM 
(
  SELECT contact_id 
   FROM contacts 
    WHERE acc_id = 1 AND email LIKE "paul%"
) AS c0 
LEFT JOIN contact_tags AS c1 
ON c1.contact_id = c0.contact_id 
AND (
  SELECT c0.contact_id FROM contact_tags c0 
  INNER JOIN contact_tags c1 
  on c0.contact_id = c1.contact_id 
  INNER JOIN contact_tags c2 on c1.contact_id = c2.contact_id 
  where c0.tag_id = 1 AND c1.tag_id = 2 AND c2.tag_id = 3
   ) 
 WHERE c1.id IS NOT NULL
```

However I know this is not right as i want to return just the single unique contact id which matches all conditions as above:

```
contact_id
   54
   54
   54
   54
```

If anyone could help me out with this it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why the first query does not return `50` as well?

Comment: @ypercube - sorry that is my mistake the second row should not be there. I shall remove it now

Comment: And you want a query that shows which `contact_id`s are in both lists, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select contact_id
From contacts
Where acc_id = 1 And email Like 'paul%'
    And contact_id In   (
                            Select Tags1.contact_id
                            From contact_tags As Tags1
                            Where Tags1.tag_id In(1,2,3)
                            Group By Tags1.contact_id
                            Having Count( Distinct Tags1.tag_id ) = 3
                            )
```

Or:

```
Select contact_id
From contacts
Where contact_id In (
                        Select C1.contact_id
                        From contact_tags As Tags1
                            Join contacts As C1
                                On C1.contact_id = Tags1.contact_id
                        Where Tags1.tag_id In(1,2,3)
                            And C1.acc_id = 1
                            And C1.email Like 'paul%'
                        Group By C1.contact_id
                        Having Count( Distinct Tags1.tag_id ) = 3
                        )
```

Comment: When i try to run your 2nd query I get the following error:

#1054 - Unknown column 'C1.contact_id' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'

Comment: @Paul Atkins - That's a typo. I accidentally included an alias in the main query's Where clause. Have fixed.

Comment: Thanks this seems to work exactly how I need it to. Although I cannot figure out what this line does 'Having Count( Distinct Tags1.tag_id ) = 3'. Can you recommend anywhere that I can read up on what that line achieves? Thanks

Comment: @Paul Atkins - It appeared that the what you were trying to achieve is to find contacts associated to all 3 tags (1,2,3). What I'm doing is filtering for contacts with those tags and the requiring that I get back 3 rows. If I get back less than 3 rows for a given contact, I know one of the tags is missing. I'm using Distinct because it is never stated whether a contact can have the same tag multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

To have a query that returns all contacts that would be returned from both the first **and** the second query, use this:

(assuming that the first one does not return duplicate `contact_id`s)

```
SELECT contact_id
FROM contacts 
WHERE acc_id = 1
  AND email LIKE "paul%"

  AND contact_id IN

  ( SELECT c0.contact_id 
    FROM contact_tags c0
      INNER JOIN contact_tags c1 
        ON c0.contact_id = c1.contact_id
      INNER JOIN contact_tags c2 
        ON c1.contact_id = c2.contact_id
    WHERE c0.tag_id = 1 
      AND c1.tag_id = 2
      AND c2.tag_id = 3
  )
```